# White Text instead of Black, green background, how to improve image to string accuracy?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to improve the accuracy of my image to string code, however, the background is constantly changing, from either a darker blue background to a green background while the text remains constantly white. Unfortunately most questions I've found on StackOverflow were all with black text instead of white so most preprocessing I've seen doesn't really work since the text I wish to withdraw is white, not black.

Image:
[image: text to withdraw in white]

I've tried:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray,config ='--psm 6')
```

However, the results are mediocre at best, it more often than not gets it wrong.

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour]. -- please present a [mre], or in this case, _multiple_ pictures that represent the variation you have trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the red or blue channel. That's because that distracting background is pure green, i.e. it's dark in the other channels.

Since you say your picture's background varies between green and blue, I'd recommend the red channel then.

```py
blue_channel = im[:, :, 0]
```

[image: blue channel]

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot! I managed to get it working on the image above, however, using ur method of selecting only one channel, I still can't get good results on a smaller image such as this one:
[image](https://i.gyazo.com/b09c2359255b314578854be077e3f70b.png)
It just returns either nothing, or a random word "Biya". The image is already with Red channel only selected

Comment: that picture simply has too little resolution. you can't fix that by resizing it. if you need that picture solved, you'll have to train a neural network.